Executing stored procedure delete all rows from table despite WHERE clause setting
I created this little stored procedure that deletes a row from my 'qrcode' table.
Due to the constraint, I update all child rows before, it works fine.
However, performing this procedure....deletes all rows from the table!!!!
I added a log and I see that the ID parameter is passed correctly.
This is how the delete query ignored the WHERE clause.
At worst, I should have an error, but there, no. It's quite violent.
I've searched everywhere, but I really don't understand what I'm doing here.
Anyone to help me?
Thanks in advance.
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_delete_qrcode`(   IN ID INT, OUT AFFECTED_ROWS INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    RESIGNAL;
END;
    
SELECT concat('ID=', ID) as log;

START TRANSACTION;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
update `qrcode` set `parentId`=NULL where `parentId`=ID;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

delete FROM `qrcode` where `id`=ID;

SET AFFECTED_ROWS = ROW_COUNT();
SELECT @AFFECTED_ROWS;

COMMIT;

END

The table definition :
CREATE TABLE `QRCode` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank` int DEFAULT '0',
  `enabled` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `createdBy` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedBy` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_QRCode_ParentId` (`parentId`),
  CONSTRAINT `qrcode_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parentId`) REFERENCES `QRCode` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

By performing the same operation in the SQL Workbench editor, it works!
Obviously, I don't understand anything! Please help.
SET @ID =28;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
update `qrcode` set `parentId`=NULL where `parentId`=@ID;
delete FROM `qrcode` where `id`=@ID;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;


You have found why I always prefix procedure argument with _.  Note: id and ID are the same.  But _id is different.

Try not use ID as parameter in stored procedure.
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_delete_qrcode`(   IN delete_id INT, OUT AFFECTED_ROWS INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    RESIGNAL;
END;
    
SELECT concat('ID=', delete_id) as log;

START TRANSACTION;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
update `qrcode` set `parentId`=NULL where `parentId`=delete_id;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

delete FROM `qrcode` where `id`=delete_id;

SET AFFECTED_ROWS = ROW_COUNT();
SELECT @AFFECTED_ROWS;

COMMIT;

END



Be mindful of identifier case-sensitivity. If you are going to call your table QRCode, then reference it as such, otherwise you will get bitten when you find yourself deploying to a platform that is case-sensitive.

As explained by Akina in his answer, you need to be mindful of variable scope.

There is no need to turn off FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS.

SELECT @AFFECTED_ROWS; should be SELECT AFFECTED_ROWS;


Here's a db<>fiddle.
You can achieve the desired functionality with ON DELETE SET NULL.
FOREIGN KEY (`parentId`) REFERENCES `QRCode` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL

Here's another db<>fiddle.

Thank you very much for this additional information

Use local variables names which are equal to the columns names NEVER !!!
When they have the same name (case-insensitively) then the name is unconditionally treated as a variable name. Hence your
... where `id`=ID ...

compares a variable and a variable, so it is always TRUE (until the variable is NULL).
Or at least specify the table alias: ... where qrcode.id=ID .... In this case qrcode.id cannot be treated as a variable..
